# How to solve syntax error in dynamic SQL in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with this part of dynamic SQL query that says syntax error near ':',

```
[PersonnelNo] + '+ :+ ' + [FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName] AS Result
```

also I don't know how to use another variable(keyword) in the query:

```
[FirstName] LIKE N'%'+ @KeyWord +'%'
```

here it's the query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ret_RetiredPersonnel_Search]
@KeyWord nvarchar (32),
@WhereClause varchar(MAX) 
AS
Exec('
SELECT 
    [Guid],
    [FirstName],
    [LastName],
    [PersonnelNo],
    [PersonnelNo] + '+ :+ ' + [FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName] AS Result
FROM ret_RetiredPersonnel 
WHERE 
    ([FirstName] LIKE N'%'+ @KeyWord +'%' OR
    [LastName] LIKE N'%'+ @KeyWord +'%' OR
    [PersonnelNo] LIKE N'%'+ @KeyWord +'%') @WhereClause
ORDER BY [LastName] DESC, [FirstName] DESC, [PersonnelNo] DESC')
```

Comment: *+ :+* - whataver this is supposed to be it's a syntax error - the whole statement is a syntax error pretty much, you should be using `''` to represent single quotes, *@whereClause* is a syntax error and if you got it to work it could be a [SQL Injection disaster](https://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasting in a whole WHERE clause is dangerous if it includes any data the user entered directly because it could open you to a [SQL injection attack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-ver15).

In what you have you have three problems:

1. `'` must be esaped ast `''` in dynamic SQL.
2. you must use `sp_executesql` instead of `exec` if you're passing parameters.
3. You should `print` your dynamic SQL to troubleshoot it

So, something like

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ret_RetiredPersonnel_Search]
@KeyWord nvarchar (32),
@WhereClause varchar(MAX) 
AS
/*
  exec [ret_RetiredPersonnel_Search] 'a', 'and FirstName = ''Fred'''
*/
    begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
    SELECT 
        [Guid],
        [FirstName],
        [LastName],
        [PersonnelNo],
        [PersonnelNo] + ''+ :+ '' + [FirstName] + '' '' + [LastName] AS Result
    FROM ret_RetiredPersonnel 
    WHERE 
        ([FirstName] LIKE N''%''+ @KeyWord +''%'' OR
        [LastName] LIKE N''%''+ @KeyWord +''%'' OR
        [PersonnelNo] LIKE N''%''+ @KeyWord +''%'') ' + @WhereClause + '
    ORDER BY [LastName] DESC, [FirstName] DESC, [PersonnelNo] DESC'

    --print @sql
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@KeyWord nvarchar (32)', @KeyWord = @KeyWord
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As your query is inside an exec,  you have to write '''  each time you want a '. Always double it

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.